# Qt C++ No output to stdout when console application is executed directly

Tags: c++, qt, console, stdout

I'm new to Qt and used the example project xmlstreamlint. When I do a printf in main I see the output when I run the application from QT Creator. But when I navigate to the debug directory and run the exe from a command shell I see no output.

I searched the internet for hours and tried things like this:

```
//freopen ("/dev/tty", "a", stdout);
QTextStream(stdout) << "string to print" << endl;
qDebug("Hallo q1");
qStdOut() << "Hallo\n";
std::cout << "\nHello World!\n";
std::cout << "Hallo" <<endl;
fflush(stdout);
```

freopen crashes when run from QT Creator and it doesn't when running the exe from command shell. 
My project file looks like this (it comes from the example)

```
CONFIG   += console
CONFIG   -= app_bundle
QT       -= gui
QT       += xml
SOURCES  += main.cpp

# install
target.path = $$[QT_INSTALL_EXAMPLES]/xml/xmlstreamlint
INSTALLS += target
```

I need help. Absolutely no output when executed from the command shell. Even with qDebug().
Maybe the wrong exe? I found xmlstreamlint.exe in 
  C:\Qt\Examples\Qt-5.7\xml\build-xmlstreamlint-Desktop_Qt_5_7_0_MSVC2013_64bit-Debug\debug
and the date is updated each time I build.
That kills me...

Thanks for any ideas.

Comment: Sorry, can't reproduce with MSVC2015. `printf()` should work from a one-line C program, try that first without any IDE or anything else. Open up a clean command shell, run `vcvars.bat x86` (give the full path to vcvars for your VS install), then use `cl.exe` to compile a `main.c` that consists of nothing else but `#include <stdio.h>` `int main() { printf("Hello, world\n"); }`

Comment: Once you get standard output working from a basic `C` program compiled directly, you can give that same program a try from within Qt Creator. It should still work with `CONFIG -= QT` `TEMPLATE=app` `CONFIG += console`. Once that works, try with `CONFIG -= QT` removed. And so on. You can't just throw such a question out without showing what steps work. If you can't get a C program to work with standard output, your question won't have anything to do with either C++ or Qt.

Comment: #include <QCoreApplication>
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    printf("Hello World");
    return 0; //a.exec();
}

Comment: I created a Hello world program and it works outside of QT. Not sure how to easily include that into a QT project so I built a new console project and added printf("Hello World").  As before: I see the output when executed from QT Creator. But when I run the executable from command shell I see no output. Then I removed all that came from QT: #include <QCoreApplication>  and call to QCoreApplication . Now I see the printf output even when running the program from command shell. So creating an instance of QCoreApplication seems to disable stdout? Why does this only happen to me?

Comment: I don't know. Get a debug build of Qt, and trace exactly what happens inside of `QCoreApplication` constructor. Then edit said constructor to remove chunks of code, rebuild Qt, and see at what point it stops breaking. Narrow it down by bisection until you can point to a WINAPI call or calls that are wrong. Then decide whether it's a Qt bug or by design, or something else (e.g. local weirdness). Once you have a debug build of Qt, a rebuild should take a few seconds - note that you must manually rebuild the core module. So it should be quick.

Comment: As a first step, leave `#include <QCoreApplication>` in and see that simply not constructing the application fixes the issue. Then you can be sure that the constructor is to blame.

Comment: When I remove the call to the constructor and keep the #include there is still no output. When I remove the #include I see the output. BUT: The output is still there when I re-include the #include. Ah - OK. when I clean the project and remove the constructor but keep the #include then I see the output. So it really is the call to the constructor. Not the #include. Will see what I can do wrt a debug build of Qt...

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes qDebug() do not print out to console even in debug mode, that’s because this function is follow qtlogging.ini file’s configuration. For me, I’m current using CentOS Firstly, locate the file:

```
[root@localhost build]# locate qtlogging.ini
/usr/share/qt5/qtlogging.ini
```

Secondly, modify the Rules in line 2, modify `*.debug=false` to `*.debug=true`

```
[root@localhost build]# cat /usr/share/qt5/qtlogging.ini
[Rules]
*.debug=true
qt.qpa.xcb.xcberror.warning=false
```